# perl Openssh ConnectionTimeout not working

Tags: perl, amazon-ec2, openssh

I have a perl script starts an EC2 instance and then uses Net::OpenSSH to connect and run some commands.

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new( $username . "\@" . $host, 
          key_path => $key_path,
          master_opts => [-o => "ConnectionAttempts=30", -o => "ConnectTimeout=30"] );

if ( $ssh->error ) {
  die "Timeout: " . $ssh->error . "\n";
}
```

This doesn't appear to be working - this should try for 15 minutes, and then quit, but it returns almost immediately.  I never get the Timeout: error message, so ssh is not returning an error.

Is this the correct syntax?  Is there a better way to deal with the fact that the EC2 instance may take a few minutes before it is available?

Comment: So what error does it return with?

Comment: @darch - it doesn't return an error, but doesn't appear to re-try - the rest of the script dies because the connection doesn't exist.  And it's dying a minute after it's started, so it's not waiting & retrying.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep harping on this, but your phrasing leaves a little doubt.  `new` always returns a new object, even if an error occurred.  `$ssh->error` should contain the reason the connection did not come up.  Are you saying that `$ssh->error` is empty?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that it does not attempt to connect 30 times, waiting 30 seconds between attempt.  I'll check the $ssh->error, but I don't think that's relevant to the question.

Comment: Errors such as look-up failures would stop ssh from retrying.

Comment: Use the constructor `timeout` option instead.

Comment: @darch - I added the error checking, and $ssh->error is empty.

Answer (score 0):

As per CPAN documentation I can see that `ConnectionAttempts` and `ConnectTimeout` should go to `default_ssh_opts` instead of `master_opts`. Please try that out.